# Change backcolor on selected menu item asp.net masterpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications

I have a menu in a MasterPage constructed of unordered list. I am trying to use javascript to change selected tab color. It works fine if i have href="#" in the anchor tags, but if I put an actual link to another page then the color tab reverts back to the home page. I change the listitem id to onlink when selected. 
I have been searching for couple days with dead end answers. Is there a clean solution for this?

How does stackoverflow accomplish this in their menu?
[Questions] [Tags] [Users] [Badges] [Unanswered]

Html for menu

```
  <div id="navbar">
        <ul id="menulist">
            <li><a onclick="SelectedTab(this);" href="Default.aspx" id="onlink">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">View</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="SelectedTab(this);" href="About.aspx" id="">About</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="SelectedTab(this);" href="Contact" id="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectedTab(sender) {
        var aElements = sender.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a");
        var aElementsLength = aElements.length;
        var index;
        for (var i = 0; i < aElementsLength; i++) {
            if (aElements[i] == sender)        
            {
                index = i;
                aElements[i].id = "onlink";
            } else {
                aElements[i].id = "";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Css for the selected tab

```
...stuff

#navbar ul li a#onlink
{
   background: #FFF;
   color: #465c71;
}
#navbar ul li a#onlink:hover 
{
   background: #FFF;
   color: #465c71;

...more stuff
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the selected link when you actually move to that page. Try something like this.

```
$(function(){
    var url=document.location.href;
    $("div#navbar ul#menulist li a").each(function(){
            var t=$(this).attr("href");
            if(t && url.indexOf(t)>0){
                $(this).addClass("onlink");
            }
    });
});
```

please check if the `navbar` and `menulist` are the IDs of rendered elements. Otherwise you either need to use 'ClientIdMode="Static"' on `div` and `ul` or use `'<%= navbar.ClientID%>'` to get id. see the working example  here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/LEa77/1/)

Also you need to make slight change to your `CSS`, instead of:

```
 #navbar ul li a#onlink
```

please use:

```
 #navbar ul li a.onlink
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you. Are there other ways to accomplish this without javascripting or is this the common way to do it?